# Does the value type variable violates the LIFO nature of stack

Tags: c#, variables, memory, stack, allocation

I have assigning a value to value type say for an example

```
int i=0;
int j=1;
```

Since `int` is a value type variable the memory is allocated in the Stack as follows(push the value of I and j to stack):

```
|_|<-- stack top
|1|<--j value
|0|<--i value
```

I have few doubts regarding this allocation :

- If i execute `i+=1` in this time what will be the changes in the stack allocation?
- How it is possible to pop the value of `i` without poping `j`
- if i re assign the of `i` then the value will be stored in the stack top, in this time what happens to the previously assigned value:

Comment: Can you explain this: `in the 0th position the value should be 0
now after adding the value it should allocate on the 1st position`?

Comment: Why do you think the second line doesn't just use "0th position"? If you've said "i is the 0th position", why does i suddenly jump to the 1st position?

Answer (score 3):

Your mental model is badly broken, you take the word "stack" too literally.  The processor stack behaves like a stack only when one method calls another.  Within a method, the arguments and local variables are stored in a `stack frame`.  It is freely addressable, no pushes or pops.  Always as offsets from either the base pointer register or stack pointer register.  EBP in 32-bit code, RSP in 64-bit code.  The size of the stack frame depends on the number of local variables.  It is "allocated" simply by decrementing the stack pointer by the frame size.  And "destroyed" simply by restoring the stack pointer.

You'd be closer if you model it as a C# `Stack<object[]>` data structure.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#STACK-FRAME) should help to clarify the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Local variables are not pushed and popped when you create and read them.

In the start of the method is code to create a stack frame to make room for local variables. This is done by moving the stack pointer to create a memory area on the stack that the method can use.

Each local variable has a fixed position in the stack frame from the start, even if the scope of a variable is smaller than the method. The stack frame doesn't change during the execution of the method.

```
|                        |
| More stack data        |
|                        |
+------------------------+
| Method return address  |
+------------------------+
| i                      | Stack frame
| j                      |
+------------------------+
<--- stack pointer
```

Typically the `bp` register is set to point to the stack frame, so `[bp + 0]` accesses `i` and `[bp + 4]` accesses `j`.

At the end of the method there is code to remove the stack frame by putting the stack pointer back, so that the return address is next to be popped.

(Note that this is an implementation detail, and the JIT compiler might for example use a register to store a variable instead of space in the stack frame, and when closures come into the picture it changes things, but it works as a starting point for understanding how local variables work.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to take into consideration the following information:

1. C# is a *just in time compiled* language, and the .NET CLR is responsible for producing machine code from .NET code during program execution.
2. Modern CPUs have a register set that are used intensively to avoid the need of going to stack for each operation.

Therefore, in your code, the **.NET CLR will most likely place i and j variables into registers** and most likely will arrange the code so that only when there are no more registers to use, temporary variables will be placed on the stack.

However that stack is not a plain LIFO structure. Accesses to stack variables can be made using EBP and ESP registers as base respectively offsets.